# How to change image src when parent has a specific class?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the image by looking at the parent class to see if it has "trophy unearned" in it.

```
<picture class="trophy unearned">
<img src="https://i.psnprofiles.com/games/97e037/trophies/1Sac8cd2.png">
</picture>
```

So when any picture in the page has "trophy unearned" as class, the img src will be replaced by:

```
<img src="https://psnprofiles.com/lib/img/icons/40-hidden.png">
```

What code can I use it in Tampermonkey?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the elements to then modify.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.trophy.unearned > img')
   .forEach(img => img.src = 'https://psnprofiles.com/lib/img/icons/40-hidden.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use vanilla `javacript` to find the image tag and replace it's source.

```js
let img = 'https://psnprofiles.com/lib/img/icons/40-hidden.png';
document.querySelector('.trophy.unearned img').src = img;
```

```html
<picture class="trophy unearned">
  <img src="https://i.psnprofiles.com/games/97e037/trophies/1Sac8cd2.png">
</picture>
```